# Xcode 5 can't find header files in usr/include

Tags: c++, xcode, path, xcode5, header-files

Im working on a C++ project in Xcode with some external header files and Xcode is unable to find header files in **usr/include**

I have also tried adding **usr/include** in Search Header Files Path but it's not working
However Xcode can find all the header files in **usr/local/include** when I add **usr/local/include** in Search Header Files but not in **usr/include**

**usr/include** doesn't work in Header Search Paths but **usr/local/include** works. Am I missing something? Permission settings or anything for **usr/include**

**Updated**

Also gives error (ld: library not found for -lGLEW.1.11.0) when I add **usr/lib** but works for **usr/local/lib**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else works, you can always add the include directory manually by specifying `-I/usr/include` in `Other C++ Flags`.

**EDIT after comments:**

In a similar fashion, you can add `-lGLEW1.11.11.0 -L/usr/lib` in `Other Linker Flags`.

Comment: It is working for usr/include now, but now linker can't find library with required flags in usr/lib

Comment: ld: library not found for -lGLEW.1.11.0 when I add usr/lib but works for usr/local/lib